# Is the Bendix/King KMD-550 airplane icon always oriented to the north?

Tags: avionics, gnss, cessna-182

I have a 2001 Cessna 182T with King avionics. The KMD-550 moving map display correctly shows "track up" but the little airplane icon is always pointed to the north.

How can I set this so that it points track up as well, or is there some kind of fault with the unit?

Comment: Does the aircraft icon rotate if the map is set to "North Up"?

Comment: Can you please add a picture? [This PDF (p.18)](http://www.bendixking.com/HWL/media/Pilot-Guides/006-18223-0000_8.pdf) states that `Aircraft Symbol - Indicates present aircraft position and heading (if
available) or track.` Do you require some additional circuitry or subscription to show actual heading?

Comment: This is really a question you should be asking Honeywell/Bendix-King (or your dealer), but do you mean "points *north*" or "points ***up***"? As I understand it the latter is expected behavior with the KMD-550 in "track up" mode: The airplane's nose will point along the current GPS track (or heading, if you have a heading input), which is "up" on your display in "track up" mode. If the nose is pointing to "north" rather than along your track you may have found a bug, but only Honeywell could say for sure.

Comment: does it say "no hdg or trk" at the top of the screen?  or perhaps "[mag/tru] ### trk"?  if the first, your unit is not getting heading data.  if the second, your unit is functioning normally.

Comment: @voretaq7 - I think you've got the correct answer, which is where I was heading (heading, get it?). If you want to put that in an answer form...

Comment: I'll take a picture when I fly this weekend. The airplane icon is always pointed north - not up. The map is arranged track up. I didn't see any warning of "no hug or trk" but I will look. I've got my avionics person looking at it right now and he thinks it might be a problem with the heading source because the traffic system is giving heading source failure errors as well. I'll update when I know more.

Comment: @voretaq7 Wanna write an answer so this disappears from the Unanswered list? :)

Comment: Here is what we've done: removed WX-500 to see if that was confusing things (no), used another KMD-540 unit to see if that was bad (no), checked the X-Y-Z lines 3 times (ok - apparently). The only thing left to do is to replace the KTA-810 with a known good unit and that hasn't been possible yet. I'm trying, believe me! One note though - a workaround is that if you're on the traffic page, it uses the antenna's orientation so the data is correct. Not great and not useful with the map, but better than nothing. I'm still working with my avionics tech to solve the problem. Thanks and stay tuned.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [Source](http://dynonavionics.com/cgi-bin/yabb2/YaBB.pl?num=1377362608/4):

> The bottom is for the icon in track up mode. For the North up mode, It
>   Depends on the Heading. The fix icon should be placed on one of the 8
>   positions (up left, up right, up center, bottom left, bottom right,
>   bottom center). For example, if the Heading is 45°, the fix icon is
>   placed on the bottom left part of the screen.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that I had posted this a while ago. Short answer: equipment failure. Each component in the system has its own internal heading source:
- Stormscope
- HSI
- Traffic advisory system

If one of these doesn't work - the little airplane points the wrong way. There is no visible failure message. In fact, I replaced the KMD-550 with a Garmin GTN 750 and the problem stuck around. I had to send the traffic advisory system away for a very expensive repair... wish I had known before I bought the plane.